# An application of LDPC codes

Tags: coding-theory

The following problem is an application of LDPC codes in communication system that I encountered and I am trying to verify if it is correct, as there is no explanation given within the text.

A $\frac{3}{4}$ LDPC parity check matrix is being used to encode incoming bits of length $x$ bits.

The Application states that:

- The maximal number of data bits is $168$ bits (which I agree as $(\frac{n-k}{n}=\frac{3}{4} \rightarrow k = 168)$.
- The number of LDPC codewords is calculated as $$N_{CW} =1+\lceil \frac{x}{168}\rceil$$
- The number of bits in the codeword

  $$L_{DCW} =\lceil \frac{x}{N_{CW}-1}\rceil$$

  - It is then stated that each data word is padded with zeros to create 504 total bits and to each data word 168 parity bits are added to create the final codeword $c$ such that $Hc^T=0$ ($H$ being the parity check matrix)

$$ c= B_1\cdots B_{L_{DCW}},0,\cdots,0,p_1,\cdots,p_{168}  $$

My questions:

1. Why do we have 1+ term in $N_{CW}$. More precisely I would have thought that the number of codeword should be $$N_{CW} =\lceil \frac{x}{168}\rceil$$
2. How come we need to recalculate the number of bits, in other words why is that $L_{DCW}\neq 168$
3. Why are bits padded with zeroes to end up with length of 504 ? and why is it that it happens to be that the parity bits are 168 bits in length equal to number of maximal data bits?

Any thoughts ?

Comment: The number of code words for a binary linear code where there are $k$ data bits is $2^k$. So, you've got a lot of things wrong here.

Comment: Not sure if I made this clear in my problem, $x$ is the total length to be encoded, for example $x$= 4096 bytes.

Comment: My point still stands.

Comment: by number of codewords I dont mean the number of available codewords in a code, I mean the number of codewords after you do encoding for the length $x$. For example number of codewords to be transmitted over channel Do your point still stand?

Comment: Yes. It does. The number of code words you can send if you have x data bits is $2^x$. Each message maps to a unique code word and you hAve $2^x$ possible messages.